# convert dict in list to one dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
result = [{u'timestamp': 1464246000, u'value': 36.9},
          {u'timestamp': 1464246900, u'value': 34.61},
          {u'timestamp': 1464247200, u'value': 34.84}]
zzz = {}
for x in result:
    zzz[x['timestamp']] = x['value']
print zzz
```

{1464246000: 36.9, 1464247200: 34.84, 1464246900: 34.61}

But, I need some like this(dict comprehension):

```
lst = [{'1': 'A'},{'2': 'B'},{'3': 'C'}]
print {k:v for x in lst for k,v in x.items()}
{'2': 'B', '3': 'C', '1': 'A'}
```

How to do this ?

Comment: See: http://blog.revathskumar.com/2011/10/python-merge-dictionaries.html

Comment: You are already doing that. What is your question?

Comment: Keys in dicts have to be unique.  Post the desired output for zzz

Comment: see how to post a question [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: >You are already doing that. What is your question?

I need convert list[{key1: value1, key2: value2}] to dict key1: value2 with construction some like this {k:v for x in lst for k,v in x.items()}

Comment: @some_vasya - And you _are_. The sample code you posted _already does that_, and it _already works_.

Comment: are you after `{d['timestamp']:d['value'] for d in result}`?

Comment: yes, {d['timestamp']:d['value'] for d in result}. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
result = [{u'timestamp': 1464246000, u'value': 36.9},
          {u'timestamp': 1464246900, u'value': 34.61},
          {u'timestamp': 1464247200, u'value': 34.84}]
```

`result` is a list of dictionaries.

To create dictionary of values from a list of dictionaries:

```
{dictionary['timestamp']:dictionary['value'] for dictionary in result}
```

Output:

```
{1464246000: 36.9, 1464247200: 34.84, 1464246900: 34.61}
```

Hence making value pairs {`val0_1: val0_2, val1_1:val1_2, ..}`

Comment: Why the down-vote?